# web.config 1.0 and 3.5

Tags: c#

I had a problem I had two web site one of them with .net 3.5 and other with 1.0 and I want to run 1.0 in 3.5 but I could not and i tried to copy some section from 1.0 to 3.5 as

I copied this section

```
<add key="ConnectionString" value="data source=.;persist security info=True;user id=Sharp;Password=#Sharp;initial catalog=Sharp" /> 

<add key="ACProduct_Upload" value="SiteUploads/ACProducts/" /> 
<add key="ACPDF_Upload" value="SiteUploads/ACPDF/" /> 
<add key="ACCertifications_Upload" value="SiteUploads/ACCertifications/" /> 

<add key="Certifications_Upload" value="SiteUploads/Certifications/" /> 

<add key="flash" value="flash/" /> 
<add key="Product_Upload" value="SiteUploads/Products/" /> 
<add key="PDF_Upload" value="SiteUploads/PDF/" /> 
<add key="HTML_Upload" value="SiteUploads/HTML_Uploads/" /> 
<add key="WallPaper_Upload" value="SiteUploads/WallPapers/" /> 
<add key="News_Upload" value="SiteUploads/News/" /> 
<add key="mailserver" value="111.111.1.1" /> 
<add key="fromEmail" value="info@example.com" />
```

to 3.5 here

```
<add key="ACProduct_Upload" value="SiteUploads/ACProducts/" /> 
<add key="ACPDF_Upload" value="SiteUploads/ACPDF/" /> 
<add key="ACCertifications_Upload" value="SiteUploads/ACCertifications/" /> 

<add key="Certifications_Upload" value="SiteUploads/Certifications/" /> 

<add key="flash" value="flash/" /> 
<add key="Product_Upload" value="SiteUploads/Products/" /> 
<add key="PDF_Upload" value="SiteUploads/PDF/" /> 
<add key="HTML_Upload" value="SiteUploads/HTML_Uploads/" /> 
<add key="WallPaper_Upload" value="SiteUploads/WallPapers/" /> 
<add key="News_Upload" value="SiteUploads/News/" /> 
<add key="mailserver" value="192.168.6.3" />
```

```
<add name="Sharp" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=SharpHA;User ID=SharpHA;Password=#SharpHA;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

but this problem apear

Only one element allowed per config file and if present must be the first child of the root element.

please any one help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you create multiple `<appSettings />` sections?

Answer (score 0):

If `<configSections>` is present, it must be the first child of the root `<configuration>` element.